# filtering individual value in a array response based on it's latest date

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two arrays a and b

I want to append the `remarks` and `delivery_status` of array `a` to array `b` based on latest `created_date_time` of array `a`.

`po_number` should be used as comparing parameter. since it is a common field in both arrays

how to do this?

```
a=[{
    actual_delivery_date: "2020-10-22"
    created_date_time: "2020-10-24T22:18:29Z"
    delivery_status: "Delivered"
    id: 16
    po_number: 1125
    remarks: "test"
    user: "pruser5"
},
{
    actual_delivery_date: "2020-10-22"
    created_date_time: "2020-10-24T22:18:29Z"
    delivery_status: "Delivered"
    id: 16
    po_number: 1124
    remarks: "test1"
    user: "pruser5"
},
{
    actual_delivery_date: "2020-10-29",
    created_date_time: "2020-10-24T23:02:05Z",
    delivery_status: "Late",
    id: 22,
    po_number: 1125,
    remarks: "asd",
    user: "pruser7"
}]
```

```
    b= [{
        po_num: 1125,
        priority: "Medium",
        processId: "30820307",
        },
        {
        po_num: 1124,
        priority: "Large",
        processId: "30820308",
    }]
```

Output I want,

```
b= [{
        po_num: 1125,
        priority: "Medium",
        processId: "30820307",
        delivery_status: "Delivered",
        remarks: "test"
        },
        {
        po_num: 1124,
        priority: "Large",
        processId: "30820308",
        delivery_status: "Late",
        remarks: "asd"
    }]
```

Comment: There are two objects with same `po_number` in array `a`. The values of only first will be used?

Comment: no, i want to append object values with latest `created_data_time` to array `b`. `po_number` and `po_num` are common field in array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you only want to append parts of A onto B if firstly, they have the same `po_number`, and then you only want to append the one with the latest `created_date_time`.

One way to do this would be to:

1. Order A by the `created_date_time` (latest date first)
2. Loop through B
3. For each item in B, use the `find` method on A to get the entry with the same po_number as the current B entry
4. Pull out the `delivery_status` and `remarks` from the found item in A, and add it to the current B entry

Code:

```
a.sort((x, y) => y.created_date_time.localeCompare(x.created_date_time));
for (const bEntry of b) {
  const matchedEntryA = a.find(aEntry => bEntry.po_num === aEntry.po_number);
  if (matchedEntryA) {
    bEntry.delivery_status = matchedEntryA.delivery_status;
    bEntry.remarks = matchedEntryA.remarks;
  }
}
```

It's worth noting that in your expected output example, b with `po_num: 1125` has `remarks: test_1`, which isn't the entry in A with the latest `created_date_time` for 1125. I believe it should be `remarks: asd` instead.

If you do want this code to get your expected answer, change my first line of code to: `a.sort((x, y) => x.created_date_time.localeCompare(y.created_date_time));` (switched y and x in the sort compareFunction return)

It's also worth noting that if you expect A to be really long, there may be more efficient ways to do this by skipping the sort step and using a different data structure.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Providing you hints so that you can try yourself.

You can instantiate a map, then loop over Array `a` to add `po_number` as key and `deliver_status`, `created_date` and `remarks` in a object as value. If the value is already present, then compare the created date, replace the value in map if already added date is less. Then loop over Array `b` to and get value of `po_num` from the map, add the `deliver_status` and `remarks` from map value to the item of Array `b`.

You can use Array's `reduce` method for iterating over Array `a` and producing a map. For Array `b`, you can use Array's `map` method.